# Are "What is the fastest way of..." questions inherently bad?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463604/what-is-the-fastest-method-of-getting-a-screenshot-in-python) and within a couple minutes it already had downvotes.

I was aware of the question coming off as suggestion-based, so I added a note at the bottom to explain why this was a good question.

Are questions that start with "What is the fastest way of..." inherently considered suggestion or opinion based? Is there a better way of phrasing things so a question doesn't get downvoted?

Comment: Almost invariably, the OP's don't specify what they want to be fast.  I prefer designs that are quickly and easily tested and debugged, since that's where the most effort is required during development, and optimzing that aspect results in the fastest development.

Comment: Despite the title, your question itself is clearly asking us to find something for you.  That is always off topic.  You probably also have google.  Thats where you ask this type of question.

Comment: @JK isn't that what stack overflow does? Find solutions to problems that people can't solve on their own or with the help of Google, either because they don't have the expertise or don't know where to look? (Personally, I spent hours looking up different ways to take screenshots, and was happy to just find one that works. I'm hoping that by asking I can help somebody else find a way, or even a better, faster way, within seconds by using Google and having the question pop up.)

Answer (score 9):

Asking "What is the fastest way..." is like asking "What is the best..." in that it's too broad and can lead to people giving opinions rather than factual answers.

Also it will depend on the particular circumstances the OP finds themselves in so the answers won't be applicable to other scenarios.

It's better to ask "How can I speed this up" with details about why it's considered slow and what the targets are. Then people can answer with specific improvements to the code or changes to the algorithm that will produce faster code.

These answers can also help future visitors as then can see a specific problem and a specific set of answers and relate that to their problem and hopefully apply the solution - or a variation of the problem - to their code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between "opinion-based" and "too broad" that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Wouldn't a _How can I speed this up?_ question be more appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke While good "how to make it better" question likely be on-topic on CR (as to improve something you'd need it working correctly first), but may not actually achieve the goal as speeding things up frequently require significant changes beyond just improvement of existing code. (Note that question linked by OP has zero code and does not fit to SO or CR)